# OWL negate object property

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have a small toy ontology in protege and I want to represent that "a duck that is only white is an AlbinoDuck"

This is my ontology

[image: Duck ontology]

I also created the property `hasColor`

I have the general class axiom for `NormalDuck` as `Duck and (hasColor some Color) SubClassOf NormalDuck` because if it's a Duck and it has any color then it's a NormalDuck (I don't care if Albino Ducks are also considered Normal)

Then for `AlbinoDuck` I have `hasColor only White SubClassOf AlbinoDuck`

Now, I have created two individuals:

- `ThisIsNormalDuck` with types `Duck`, `hasColor some Black`, `hasColor some White`. This represents a Black and white duck.
- `ThisIsAlbinoDuck` with types `Duck` and `hasColor some White`.

However, when I run the Reasoner the class `NormalDuck` is inferred for both individuals. What I expected was that `ThisIsAlbinoDuck` would be both Normal and Albino.

I have two questions about this:

- What I want to define is that `AlbinoDucks` can only have a single color and it has to be white. how can I do this in protege/owl language?
- What if I want to define "Something that is White and could have other colors but not brown"? (it could be `White` or `White and Black`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your ontology:

1. `hasColor only White SubClassOf AlbinoDuck` means the `hasColor only White` set is a subset of the `AlbinoDuck` set. Thus it is possible to have individuals that belong to the AlbinoDuck set but the `hasColor only White` set. You need to use `EquivalentTo` rather than `SubsetOf`.

   ```
   Class: AlbinoDuck
      EquivalentTo:
      hasColor only White
      SubClassOf:
        Duck
   ```
2. Stating that `ThisIsAlbinoDuck` has type `hasColor some White` says that it has the color white, but is does not exclude the possibility that it also could have other colours. To force it not have other colors you should

(a) ensure that the only colors you can have are `White`, `Black` and `Brown` and

```
 Class: Color
   DisjointUnionOf:
     Black, Brown, White
```

(b) state that `ThisIsAlbinoDuck` does not have the colors `Black` and `Brown`.

```
  Types:
    Duck,
    not (hasColor some (Black or Brown)),
    hasColor some Color
```

The complete ontology looks as follows:

```
   ObjectProperty: hasColor

   Class: AlbinoDuck
      EquivalentTo:
      hasColor only White
      SubClassOf:
        Duck

   Class: Black
      SubClassOf:
        Color

   Class: Brown
      SubClassOf:
        Color

   Class: Color
      DisjointUnionOf:
         Black, Brown, White

   Class: Duck
      DisjointUnionOf:
      AlbinoDuck, NormalDuck

   Class: NormalDuck
      EquivalentTo:
        hasColor some (Black or Brown)
      SubClassOf:
        Duck

    Class: White
      SubClassOf:
        Color

   Individual: albinoDuck
      Types:
        Duck,
        not (hasColor some (Black or Brown)),
        hasColor some Color

    Individual: normalDuck
       Types:
       Duck,
         (hasColor some Black)
         and (hasColor some White)
```

[image: Desired inference]

Comment: What if I had a thousand colors? Do I need to list them one by one as Disjoint union? Also, with this approach, if an individual `Duck` with `hasColor some White` is not inferred as either Normal or Albino

Comment: Yes, you will need the 1000 colors as disjoint. As the type for `albinoDuck` you will then prefer to have `not hasColor some (not White)` rather than adding `not` for every color other than white.

Comment: Yes,  having `hasColor some White` will not and cannot infer that a duck is normal or albino. Knowing that a duck has white is not sufficient to infer anything. What you need to know is either (1) a duck is **only white** or that (2) a duck has **at least 1 color other than white**.

Comment: On `Duck` you can add an `EquivalentTo hasColor some Color`  which will cause any individual having `hasColor some White` (or any other color) to at least classify as a `Duck`.